# how To call function on particular response in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Below object response I am getting , on FAILURE response I am trying to call function that open modal .
But I guess its wrong approach, please correct me . If I call same function button click then Modal is coming  . Please how can I open modal on failure and success I'll got o next page screen .
Please suggest me.

/// Below response //////////

```
Object response 

validateUserResponse:
reference_id: "NxNxNxNxNxNxNxNxNxNxNxN"
status: "FAILURE"
```

/////////////////////////

```
this.state={
 isModalVisible: false,
 }

_toggleModal = () =>
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: !this.state.isModalVisible });

render(){
const {validateUserResponse} = this.props;
  if (!_.isEmpty(validateUserResponse)) {
    validateUserResponse.status==='FAILURE'? this._toggleModal():LoadScreen.bind(that, 2, validateUserResponse)();
}

return (
   <View>
          <Modal
            isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}
            onBackButtonPress={() => this._toggleModal()}
            onBackdropPress={() => this._toggleModal()}
            style={{ margin: 0 }}
          >
            <View style={style.modalContainer}>
              <View style={style.innerContainer}>
                <View style={style.detailsContainer}>
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'flex-end', marginTop: -40 }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._toggleModal()} >
                      <Image source={CLOSE_W} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  </View>
                  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 10, alignContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', alignSelf: 'center' }}>
                      <IconSmall icon="report-problem" type="MaterialIcons" style={{ color: 'red', paddingRight: 5, paddingBottom: 3 }} />
                      <Text>CUSTOMER E-VALIDATION FAILED</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                      height: 2,
                      margin: 5,
                      borderBottomWidth: 1,
                      borderBottomColor: 'grey',
                      paddingBottom: 10
                    }} />
                  </View>

                  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', marginBottom: 10 }}>
                    <RegularText text={'Status'} textColor='grey' style={{ marginBottom: 5 }} />
                    <SmallText text={validateUserResponse.status} textColor='red' />
                  </View>

                  <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
                    <PrimaryBtn label={'Validate Again'} disabled={false}
                      onPress={() => this._toggleModal()} />
                  </View>

                  <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
                    <YellowBtn label={'Go to Dashboard'} disabled={false}
                      onPress={() => this._gotoDashboard()} />
                  </View>

                </View>
              </View>
            </View>
          </Modal>
        </View>
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the state in render method . "_toggleModal" is method which change state and it is bad approach.

You should use [getderivedstatefromprops](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)

> getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked right before calling the render
>   method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should
>   return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState){
   if(!_.isEmpty(nextProps.validateUserResponse) && nextProps.validateUserResponse.status==='FAILURE'){
     return { isModalVisible: true};
  }
  else return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur time , validateUserResponse  is coming from props .. and this coming after button action . I mean after submitting the form .